# Objects inhereting from the same parent class placed in ArrayList problem

Tags: java, arraylist

There is code:

```
public class Piece {
    boolean isWhite;

    public Piece(boolean isWhite) {
        this.isWhite = isWhite;
    }
}


public class Bishop extends Piece {
    public Bishop(boolean isWhite) {
        super(isWhite);
    }
}
```

So if I create 2 anonymous instances of `Bishop` and set `isWhite` differently for them, they will have it.

```
System.out.println(new Bishop(true).isWhite); // prints true
System.out.println(new Bishop(false).isWhite); // prints false
```

But when I place them into ArrayList, every instance in it will have `isWhite` of the first anonymous class, if it would called only once. i.e.

```
List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();
pieces.add(new Bishop(true));
pieces.add(new Bishop(false));

for (Piece p : pieces) {
    System.out.println(p.isWhite); // prints true for both, as first was set
}
```

It happens if I create references too, i.e.

```
Bishop b1 = new Bishop(true);
Bishop b2 = new Bishop(false);

pieces.add(b1);
pieces.add(b2);

for (Piece p : pieces) {
    System.out.println(p.isWhite) // prints true for the both
}
```

So I have no clue why does this happen =(

Comment: Can you post the complete code? as it is I don't see any issue

Comment: I really don't have any clue neither, as this should be impossible. Is your jvm drunk?

Comment: tested it, prints true and false correctly. https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/9EQ

Comment: Wow, I thought it's java peculiarity, but I were wrong...
Here is full code: https://github.com/Yonshoku/Chess2.git
ArrayList creation in Board class, pieces in pieces package. Any clue will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why do you bother with Bishop#isWhite()? You're just calling the superclass' version.

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is still bad, what do you mean? Should I delete getter of isWhite or something else? Thank you!

Comment: @Yokoton he means that there's no difference whatsoever between creating and calling isWhite on Piece or Bishop, as the second one is just another Piece. But that was exactly that mislead you at the first time: *inheriting from the same parent class...* So I guess that's why your example shows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after looking at your src, you have a mistake [here](https://github.com/Yonshoku/Chess2/blob/master/src/chessgui/Board.java).
You loop over the white pieces twice

```
public void paintPieces(Graphics g) {
    for (Piece piece : whitePieces) {
        g.drawImage(whitePiecesImages.get(piece.getType()), getXCoord(piece.getX()), getYCoord(piece.getY()), null);
        System.out.println(piece.isWhite());
    }

    for (Piece piece : whitePieces) {
        g.drawImage(blackPiecesImages.get(piece.getType()), getXCoord(piece.getX()), getYCoord(piece.getY()), null);
        System.out.println(piece.isWhite());
    }
}
```

So yes, all the `isWhite()` will tell you true for the black pieces in the System.out.

The last loop should be:

```
 for (Piece piece : blackPieces)
```

*So your JVM can keep drinking, no issues*